# Large Temporal Cache that need to be Cleared on JVM

Tags: scala, caching, jvm, bigtable

I have a in house data pipeline that need to process streams of events in a given window (few minutes) at a time. A window contains 10s of GBs of data (at least 30 million records). As internal state will be more than 1 TB, I am leveraging external KV storage (e.g. bigtable) as a durable storage for internal states. The issue is I need to keep large temporal cache in memory for a duration of window that is backed by the external KV storage to improve the latency and responsiveness of the pipeline.

If the cache state is long living, off-heap might have been a good option however for temporal states that should be cleared I am leaning toward on-heap memory, in this case heap would have to be large which is not optimal. Also GC is not on demand, so on-heap cache could potentially cause OOM.

What would be the best practices to store large amount of in-memory cache that is subject to garbage collection per some interval (window). Note: this is a Scala app on JVM.

Comment: I've used Akka Cluster Sharding for this sort of thing... it might be suitable if there's some usable partitioning for the 10s of GBs per window.  Adya's 2019 paper on Rink vs. Link stores might also be useful reading and present an alternative way to view this sort of problem that's less about caching

Comment: The mentioned Adya paper: https://research.google/pubs/pub48030/